# binding parameters in MySQl and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to learn how to use prepared statements in my PHP, to get data out from MySQL database. At the moment I am not getting anything printed out.

I need to have a while loop there is going through my rows in the database. Is that correct?

Am I on the correct way here, or what am I missing? I made some comments in the code, to describe what I am doing.

```
    <?php

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM fantasies WHERE headline = ? AND description = ? AND place = ? ORDER BY reg_date DESC LIMIT 3");

                // Execute prepared statement 
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    $success = true;
                }

                // Make variables ready
                $head = null;
                $desc = null;
                $plac = null;

                // Bind result to variables
                $stmt->bind_result($head, $desc, $plac);

                while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                    // What should go here?
                    echo "Headline: ".$head."Description: ".$desc."Place: ".$place;
                }
                // Close statement
                $stmt->close();

                // Close connection
                $mysqli->close();   

if($success) {
    echo "Selected Succesfull";
} else {
    echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: use [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check query return result or not

Comment: you execute twice

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have updated my question

Comment: you didn't use `bind_param()`; that's why your code failed @KrMa http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 1):

That code when executed it should give you an error :

> **Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound**

You need to bind your parameters as you are using placeholders

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $headline, $description, $place); //missing from your code
```

where "sss" is the dataType in this case a string and `$headline, $description, $place` are your variables that you replacing with placeholders

Your code should be

```
<?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM fantasies WHERE headline = ? AND description = ? AND place = ? ORDER BY reg_date DESC LIMIT 3");

//bind parameters
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $headline, $description, $place);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($head, $desc, $plac);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        echo "Headline: " . $head . "desc: " . $desc . "Place: " . $plac;
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {

    echo "error" . $mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see what you mean. I just tried with your code. I am still not getting anything printet out. Could it be my SELECT statement?

Comment: do u have  these variables `$headline, $description, $place`?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code and tried, but it is still not giving me any output. The columns names in my database is: `head, description, place`. Actually I am not even getting the "error" message. So it looks like nothing is called.

Comment: When I use this query: https://jsfiddle.net/r447bgr6/ I get printed my output correct.

Comment: the reason u not getting the results is because the where condition is not met, make sure it's met